# Por que essa função fatorial não funciona?

Tags: python

```
def fatorial(n):
    fat = 1
    if n == 0 or n ==1:
        return 1
    else:
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            fat=i*fat
        return fat

def main():
    n =  int(input("Digite um numero que quer ver o fatorial: "))
    print(str(n) + "! = ", fatorial(n))


    # Executanto a função main():
    main()
```

não retorna nada

Comment: Porque esta chamando ela dentro dela mesma ? Nisso o código não é executado!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss blz, é me antecipei achando que a resposta fosse uma edição, me atentarei a questionar antes.

Answer (score 3):

Não retorna nada porque você chamou a função `main` dentro dela mesma; mas como a função nunca é chamada de fora, ela não será executada. Aparentemente foi erro na indentação do código apenas, então basta recuar em um nível a chamada de `main`:

```
def fatorial(n):
    fat = 1
    if n == 0 or n ==1:
        return 1
    else:
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            fat=i*fat
        return fat

def main():
    n =  int(input("Digite um numero que quer ver o fatorial: "))
    print(str(n) + "! = ", fatorial(n))


# Executanto a função main():
main()
# ^----- Aqui, main voltou um nível de indentação
```

Se você chamar `range(1, n+1)` para `n = 0`, não será executado o laço de repetição, pois o intervalo fica `[1, 1[` e o valor que você definiu para `fat` ficaria 1, que é o resultado; semelhante acontece para quando `n = 1`, pois o intervalo será `[1, 2[`, executando para `i = 1`, ficando `fat = 1 * fat`, que ainda será 1, que também é o resultado. Ou seja, você não precisa dessa condição se `n` vale 0 ou 1:

```
def fatorial(n):
    fat = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        fat=i*fat
    return fat
```

E fazer `fat = i * fat` é o mesmo que `fat *= i`, então pode simplificar isso também:

```
def fatorial(n):
    fat = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        fat *= i
    return fat
```